# Groovy Reader HashSet on readLines() returns out of order

Tags: java, groovy, hashset, readlines

I'm VERY newb at Groovy (and most back end.) I'm typically a JS developer, so bear with me.

I have a static **.txt file that's holding a manifest**, one item per line:

```
asdf/asdf/rewer.js
asdf/asdf/opuio.js
asdf/asdf/rnieo.js
asdf/asdf/tewoe.js
```

I have successfully **read it** with `readLines()` and **converted it to an array** using `HashSet()`.

However, this array is **not in the original order** of the file... nor is it alphabetical. So I'm at a loss how this is being ordered or how to maintain the correct order.

**How can order be maintained?**

(Don't ask why I'm listing JS files in a .txt and pulling them in this way. It's a crazy,  convoluted requirement. Just looking to keep the order.)

Thanks

Comment: Hash sets make no order guarantee. Have you tried LinkedHashSet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you are using `HashSet` for this?

If you want an array of lines you can just convert the list to an array using `list.toArray()`

```
def linesAsArray = new File('file.txt').readLines().toArray()
```

Comment: I was using HashSet because I'm a newb. Works perfectly thanks for the save!

Comment: @Randy: also arrays are not idiomatic groovy, typically you use lists unless there's some ugly legacy Java thing that requires it.